# When to use the UtteranceProgressListener

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have a FrameLayout with two ImageButtons (*Play*, *Stop*). By default

*Play* button is `VISIBLE`, *Stop* button is `GONE`

Clicking the *Play* starts the TTS Engine which reads the text. On Completion of reading the text, I want to set the Visibility of

Play to `GONE`, Stop to `VISIBLE`

Should I use the UtteranceProgressListener to serve the purpose? If not,

- How can I perform the above action?
- What is the purpose of UtteranceProgressListener?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you perhaps mean that:

- reading starts -> *Play* is gone and *Stop* is visible
- reading ends -> *Play* is visible, *Stop* is gone

Anyway, the purpose of `UtteranceProgressListener` is exactly what you are describing. It's used to monitor the progress of the speech synthesis.

You can add an "utterance id" (here "helloText") to any text that is spoken out:

```
tts.speak("Hello Stack Overflow!", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, "helloText");
```

But that's not really necessary in your case, so the last parameter can be null:

```
tts.speak("Hello Stack Overflow!", TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

The `UtteranceProgressListener` should be added before calling `speak()`. You could do that for example in the TTS initialization callback `onInit()` if the TTS status is `TextToSpeech.SUCCESS`.

It can be a separate class or just an anonymous inner class:

```
speech.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
            // Speaking started. 

        }

        @Override
        public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
            // Speaking stopped.

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String utteranceId) {
            // There was an error.
        }
    });
```

The `onStart()` method is triggered when speaking starts (soon after calling `speak()`) so that's one possible place to switch the visible button. For example the *Play* button could be switched to a *Stop* button.

The `onDone()` method is triggered when speaking is finished and it's another possible place to switch the visible button. For example the *Stop* button could be switched to a *Play* button.

And as you can see the "utterance id" is available in both methods if you provided a one in the `speak()` method call. It would be useful if you needed to know exactly which text is being spoken/finished being spoken/failed with an error.

Comment: Sorry for getting back late. Tried my sweat out trying to make the UtteranceProgressListener work. But nothing fruitful as yet. Tried even using Hashmap and Bundle for UtteranceID. Probably missing something.

Comment: If possible, can you check my code snippets. I can paste the code snippets.

Comment: Can you elaborate more about *utterance id*? Why is it exactly needed?

Comment: Like said without the utterance id you'll only know that the synthesis of some text has started or ended but you do not know which text it was. In simple use cases this is not a problem and you do not need an utterance id. If you for example have an application that talks a lot and is situation aware (like a navigation app.) there may be a need to prioritize some texts over others: some may be interrupted if a more important message is queued, the more important ones can be protected from being interrupted. In this case you want to know exactly which text is currently spoken.

Comment: ...Or you might just want to trigger something visual on your UI when a certain text is spoken. Or you might want to speak out several texts in a specific order and the utterance id could correspond to the text's position in an ArrayList or something like that. It's up to your imagination.

Comment: If you have some code that still doesn't work and [previous Stack Overflow discussions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=utteranceprogresslistener) are not enough to solve it you can of course post your code to a new question.

Answer (score 5):

UtteranceProgressListener can be used to identify when the TTS  is completed. Try this following code which shows a toast after TTS completed.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{
    private boolean initialized;
    private String queuedText;
    private String TAG = "TTS";
    private TextToSpeech tts;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        tts = new TextToSpeech(this /* context */, this /* listener */);
        tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(mProgressListener);


        speak("hello world");

    }




    public void speak(String text) {

        if (!initialized) {
            queuedText = text;
            return;
        }
        queuedText = null;

        setTtsListener(); // no longer creates a new UtteranceProgressListener each time
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "MessageId");
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, map);
    }


    private void setTtsListener() {

    }





    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
            initialized = true;
            tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);

            if (queuedText != null) {
                speak(queuedText);
            }
        }
    }



    private abstract class runnable implements Runnable {
    }




    private UtteranceProgressListener mProgressListener = new UtteranceProgressListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
        } // Do nothing

        @Override
        public void onError(String utteranceId) {
        } // Do nothing.

        @Override
        public void onDone(String utteranceId) {

            new Thread()
            {
                public void run()
                {
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new runnable()
                    {
                        public void run()
                        {

                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "TTS Completed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });
                }
            }.start();

        }
    };


}
```