# TextToSpeech fails to speak huge strings

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am trying to read out the whole bible chapters using TTS. the problem is, it fails because the text length is huge.

```
  textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                int ttsLang = textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.US);

                if (ttsLang == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                        || ttsLang == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                    Log.e("TTS", "The Language is not supported!");
                } else {
                    Log.i("TTS", "Language Supported.");
                }
                Log.i("TTS", "Initialization success.");
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TTS Initialization failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

public void speak(View view) {
    int speechStatus = textToSpeech.speak(data, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    if (speechStatus == TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TTS conversion failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Log.e("TTS", "Error in converting Text to Speech!");
    }
}
```

How do I fix this?

I get this in my logs `Log.e("TTS", "Error in converting Text to Speech!");`

Comment: How do you know that the reason is because the string is too large?  Have you tried the same code with small strings?  Are you sure you're not calling speak() before the TTS object is initialized?

Comment: If the text length is a problem, then speak it in smaller chunks or "utterances". By using `TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD` you can start speaking the first utterance and add more utterances to the queue. But maybe at some point there's a limit for the queue(?) You can also [use an UtteranceProgressListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37004546/when-to-use-the-utteranceprogresslistener/37005585) to add the next utterance only after the previous one has been completely spoken out.